# SXA - Type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.Wrappers.WebEditCommandWrapper Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

I'm getting below error while opening any page in Experience Editor-

Type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.Wrappers.WebEditCommandWrapper' in Assembly 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions, Version=4.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

I've checked the logs and found a below error-

```
ERROR Application error.
```

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.**SerializationException**
Message: Type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.Wrappers.WebEditCommandWrapper' in Assembly 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions, Version=4.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
Source: mscorlib

Comment: just an update, I can confirm that It's because of Redis configuration on the CM servers,  After removing the Redis configuration the issue didn't occur, but still need to see what's wrong with the Redis configuration.. Will keep you posted!

Comment: this also happens if you have a shared/private session in SQL mode